# Should I use these, those, or their in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> With these thoughts, I closed my eyes. All I could hear now was the
>   hooting of an owl, and the leaves rustling on the ground outside.
>   **These/those/their sound/sounds** gradually soothed
>   me--and before I knew it, my mind drifted into a deep, dreamless
>   sleep.

Should I use these, those, or their in the sentence above?

Comment: Why not:... outside, which gradually...

Comment: Since you chose the past tense (was, soothed, drifted), I would go with "those" sounds.  Unless you're now talking in the present tense, remembering the sounds anew, "these" sounds odd. :-)

Comment: Or just "The sound..."

Comment: This question is off topic here (writing advice) but might be a good question for [writers].

Comment: @KitFox There were *two* sounds - the owl & the leaves. "The sounds ..." [plural] maybe.

Comment: The comma after "owl" is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the tense is strained through the whole thing.

I would want to write something like:

> With those thoughts, I closed my eyes. All I heard was the hooting of an owl, and the leaves rustling on the ground outside. The sounds gradually soothed me and I quickly drifted into a deep, dreamless sleep.

In other words, I would write around it like the above comments.